# Loading packages in Jupyter Notebook that are Octave packages

Tags: jupyter-notebook, octave

To be short and sweet I am new to Juypter Notebook and Octave together. My program is to load pkgs from octave to perform operations. I have watched some videos online but the saga doesn't show how to... I have some code but it's code I programmed in octave which I just want to load in to an octave notebook I have some options which I have tried. I programmed this in Octave and it works I just like the annotation part of the Jupyter notebook. I have the packages downloaded in Octave.

```
pkg load io; pkg load dataframe ; pkg load ltfat;
run 'C:\Octave\absorbancegraph.m'  % The necessary functions
run 'C:\Octave\ngraph.m' % The necessary functions
excel_file = 'C:\College\MasterFileLactose071019TDS.xlsx';
sheet_name1 = 'Lactose.500g.2p'; sheet_name2 =  'Lactose.425g.2p'; 
sheet_name3 = 'Lactose.375g.2p'; sheet_name4 = 'Lactose.450g.2p';
sheet_name5 = 'Serra93.4muNN1';
[absorbance1, thz] = absorbancegraph(excel_file,sheet_name1);
[absorbance2, thz] = absorbancegraph(excel_file,sheet_name2);
[absorbance3, thz] = absorbancegraph(excel_file,sheet_name3);
[absorbance4, thz] = absorbancegraph(excel_file,sheet_name4);
[refractive_index1, thz] = ngraph(excel_file,sheet_name1);
[refractive_index2, thz] = ngraph(excel_file, sheet_name2);
[refractive_index3, thz] = ngraph(excel_file, sheet_name3);
[refractive_index4, thz] = ngraph(excel_file, sheet_name4);
[refractive_index5, thz] = ngraph(excel_file, sheet_name5);
figure(1)
  set(gcf,'units','normalized','position',[0.03 0.50 0.43 0.35]);
  plot(thz,absorbance1, 'k');hold on; plot(thz, absorbance2, 'r');
  hold on; plot(thz,absorbance3,'g'); hold on; plot(thz, absorbance4, 'm');
  axis ("normal"); xax1 = 'TeraHertz (THz)' ; yax1 = 'Absorbance';
  xlim([0 3]); grid  on;
  xlabel(xax1); ylabel(yax1); title( strcat(yax1, ' of various Lactose Tablets' ));
  legend(sheet_name1,sheet_name2, sheet_name3, sheet_name4)
  set(gca);
  box on
figure(2)
  set(gcf,'units','normalized','position',[0.03 0.50 0.43 0.35]);
  plot(thz,refractive_index1, 'k'); hold on; plot(thz, refractive_index2, 'r');
  hold on; plot(thz, refractive_index3, 'g'); hold on; plot(thz, refractive_index4, 'm');
  axis ("normal"); xax1 = 'TeraHertz (THz)' ; yax1 = 'Refractive Index';
  xlim([0 3]); ylim([-10 10]); grid  on;
  xlabel(xax1); ylabel(yax1); title( strcat(yax1, ' of various Lactose, Tablets'))
  legend(sheet_name1, sheet_name2, sheet_name3, sheet_name4);
  set(gca);
  box on
figure(3)
  set(gcf,'units','normalized','position',[0.03 0.50 0.43 0.35]);
  plot(thz,refractive_index5, 'k');
  axis ("normal"); xax1 = 'TeraHertz (THz)' ; yax1 = 'Refractive Index';
  xlim([0 3]); ylim([0 4]); grid  on;
  xlabel(xax1); ylabel(yax1); title( strcat(yax1, ' of various NanoCelluose'))
  legend(sheet_name5);
  set(gca);
  box on
```

The error messages are the following

'unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I run this code in Octave and it works fine; however, I am also wondering how can I switch the kernel to use the `octave-gui.exe`, instead `octave-cli.exe.`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `octave-gui.exe` or `octave-cli.exe` to start Octave. If you need to run octave as a GUI application you need to run `octave.vbs`. It sets all environment variables that are required by Octave to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem by adding 'C:\Octave\Octave-5.1.0.0\usr\bin\' to system PATH